# Do the swagger have support for an unlimited number upload of files?

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I want to upload an unlimited number of files in nestjs/swagger.

```
@ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
@Post('upload')
@ApiImplicitFile({ name: 'files', required: true, description: 'List of cats' })
@UseInterceptors(FilesInterceptor('files'))
uploadFile(@UploadedFiles() files) {
    console.log(files);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "unlimited"? There's of course going to be a size limit for the HTTP request.

Comment: I want upload many files... In swagger in one params